# Error in SendMessageToWinControl - A control type was not specified

Tags: c#, javascript

My first question here. I hope i have luck here!!

Here it goes:

I have an webapp that creates barcodes. When I click on the button that should print it, it doesn't work.

I created an UserControl to get the COM1 port of the client barcode printer.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function SendMessageToWinControl() {
        var winCtrl = document.getElementById("PrintBarcode");

        winCtrl.SendMessage(document.form1.HiddenField1.value,
                            document.form1.HiddenField2.value,
                            document.form1.HiddenField3.value,
                            document.form1.HiddenField4.value,
                            document.form1.HiddenField5.value);
    }
</script>
```

when I create the object, it shows in the design page a message: "The control type was not specified or the specified type could not be found."

When i run the application and click on the button that should print, it shows the message:
"0x800A01B6 - Error at runtime from JavaScript: The object does not support property or method 'SendMessage'".

I am unable to put the rest of the code here, it will not appear in the text. 
Well, if anyone has any way to fix this, please let me know! I'm already crazy with this error!

I'm using c# .net language. Visual Studio 2012 Pro.

Comment: Please add any reference of third party libs you may using or the source of what is your `winCtrl`.

Comment: <object id="PrintBarcode" classid="http:codbarra.dll#codbarra.UserControl1" height="150" width="360" VIEWASTEXT> </object>
I use this code to try to get to the third part libs.